# How to restrict a user defined intent to your app

Tags: android, android-intent

If I create a user defined intent filter for a specific app, then how do I restrict or make it available from being accessed by other apps.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.opentable.action.RESERVE"/>
```

In this case the particular activity or broadcast reciever that is registered to `com.opentable.action.RESERVE` will be invoked. Is there a way that I can specify if `com.opentable.action.RESERVE` can be called from other apps as well or only restrict it my app?

Answer (score 4):

If you are defining a custom Intent action that should be internal to your application, then you do not need to define it in your Manifest file.

For example, in an app, I am using the [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) as part of a dispatcher pattern implementation. I would register a BroadcastReceiver implementation this way:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("com.example.android.MY_ACTION");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Then when I run the following code, my receiver will receive the locally broadcasted Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.android.MY_ACTION");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This way you do not need to publish your actions for other apps to possibly interact with.